# Creating executable JAR with Maven Shade plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I am having trouble making an executable jar from a simple Java program.

I followed [these Maven instructions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) and modified my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation= 
           "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>package.MyClass</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When executing the `install` goal, I can read the line:

```
[INFO] Replacing /home/project-1.0.0.jar with /home/project-1.0.0-shaded.jar
```

But all I can find at that location is the `project-1.0.0.jar`, actually containing the dependencies -and having the right size- but when trying to execute it with my jre, it says:

```
The file '/home/project-1.0.0.jar' is not marked as executable.
```

Thus nothing gets executing!

How can I get my jar to execute properly?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How did you try to execute it? It doesn't look to me as if you said, "java -jar MYJARFILE"

Comment: Well actually I had to make it executable on my Ubuntu first...

Comment: @Vakimshaar The executable flag on Ubuntu is not necessary cause it will be executed by the JVM ...and not by the os itself.

Comment: How to set it when generating the JAR then?

Comment: Have you called via "java -jar MYJARFILE" like bmargulies already mentioned?

Comment: To create a "real" executable you need to wrap your jar. For example with [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or other alternatives which you can easily fine around.

Comment: Or tell the shell how to interpret the `.jar` suffix

Comment: @JeanLogeart Did you find a solution? Hopefully you can remember. ;-)

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress I have a hard time remembering what I had for lunch today so a specific issue from 4 years ago... Nice try though ;-)

Comment: My problem turned out to be the shade execution was within a profile which I wasn't running under. Pulling it outside of the profile then created my -executable.jar. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

> Given is the **pom.xml** to create an executable jar file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.executablejar</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <docker.image.prefix>springDemo</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have a simple solution with the assembly plugin. This solution will make a jar (target/${project.groupdId}-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar):

- containing all the required dependencies
- that is executable (via java -jar *.jar)

Declare in you pom file:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>

                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>package.MyClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-executable-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I hope I helped you!
Cheers !

Comment: The author is on the right way with its shade approach.